# RDS generate_presigned_url does not support the DestinationRegion parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, boto3

I was trying to set up encrypted RDS replica in another region, but I got stuck on generating pre-signed URL.

It seems that boto3/botocore does not allow DestinationRegion parameter, which is defined as a requirement on AWS API ([link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBInstanceReadReplica.html)) in case we want to generate PreSignedUrl.

Versions used:

- boto3 (1.4.7)
- botocore (1.7.10)

Output:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "DestinationRegion", must be one of: DBInstanceIdentifier, SourceDBInstanceIdentifier, DBInstanceClass, AvailabilityZone, Port, AutoMinorVersionUpgrade, Iops, OptionGroupName, PubliclyAccessible, Tags, DBSubnetGroupName, StorageType, CopyTagsToSnapshot, MonitoringInterval, MonitoringRoleArn, KmsKeyId, PreSignedUrl, EnableIAMDatabaseAuthentication, SourceRegion
```

Example code:

```
import boto3

url = boto3.client('rds', 'eu-east-1').generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='create_db_instance_read_replica',
    Params={
        'DestinationRegion': 'eu-east-1',
        'SourceDBInstanceIdentifier': 'abc',
        'KmsKeyId': '1234',
        'DBInstanceIdentifier': 'someidentifier'
        },
    ExpiresIn=3600,
    HttpMethod=None
    )
```

Same issue [was already reported](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/951) but got closed.

Thanks for help,

Petar

Comment: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.create_db_instance_read_replica does not expect a `DestinationRegion` parameter.

Comment: That's true. But to create replica in another region you need to create pre-signed url, which requires `DestinationRegion`.

"The presigned URL must be a valid request for the CreateDBInstanceReadReplica API action that can be executed in the source AWS Region that contains the encrypted source DB instance. The presigned URL request must contain the following parameter values:

DestinationRegion - The AWS Region that the encrypted Read Replica will be created in."

Comment: @PetarKoraca Any Luck?

Answer (score 0):

Generate Pre signed URL from the source region, then populate the create_db_instance_read_replica with that url.

> The presigned URL must be a valid request for the CreateDBInstanceReadReplica API action that can be executed in the **source AWS Region** that contains the encrypted **source** DB instance
>
> PreSignedUrl (string) --
>   The URL that contains a Signature Version 4 signed request for the CreateDBInstanceReadReplica API action in the **source AWS Region** that contains the source DB instance.

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='profile_name')

url = session.client('rds', 'SOURCE_REGION').generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='create_db_instance_read_replica',
    Params={
        'DBInstanceIdentifier': 'db-1-read-replica',
        'SourceDBInstanceIdentifier': 'database-source',
        'SourceRegion': 'SOURCE_REGION'
    },
    ExpiresIn=3600,
    HttpMethod=None
)

print(url)

source_db = session.client('rds', 'SOURCE_REGION').describe_db_instances(
    DBInstanceIdentifier='database-SOURCE'
)

print(source_db)

response = session.client('rds', 'DESTINATION_REGION').create_db_instance_read_replica(
    SourceDBInstanceIdentifier="arn:aws:rds:SOURCE_REGION:account_number:db:database-SOURCE",
    DBInstanceIdentifier="db-1-read-replica",
    KmsKeyId='DESTINATION_REGION_KMS_ID',
    PreSignedUrl=url,
    SourceRegion='SOURCE'
)

print(response)
```